# Is it possible to change the MySQL server-id during a SQL session?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL 5.5 server with a server-id of 20. I want to execute a few queries on that server, but have them write to the binlog as a **different** server-id than 20. Is this possible?

I am aware `set sql_log_bin` is commonly used to turn binlogging on/off at-will, but I actually do want to execute these queries and have them written to the binlog, just as another server-id.

`set server_id=21` errors saying it needs to be global, not a session variable, so I may already have my answer, but still, I have a feeling it is possible somehow. I mean, the mysql replication slave component can do it.

Comment: You cannot control your server-id on the session level; you did indeed have your answer. The mysql replication slave component does not do it as you describe. You could possibly get away with a complext topology where slaves replicating certain databases turn to pass only certain queries. But off my sleeve this doesn't sound like something you would want.

Comment: The mysql replication slave component does do what I want. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates The log-slave-updates when enabled, will tell that host when it executes queries received from a master through replication, to write those queries to its own binlog file. It does so with the **source's** server-id. That's what I want. To do an update SQL command like coming in from a master, but not actually through replication, but as a an actual query on my SQL session. I want to do replication without using built-in replication.

Answer (score 8):

**server_id** is a dynamic variable, so you can change it while the server is running. To change the **global** variable, do:

```
SET GLOBAL server_id=21
```

More info at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options.html#option_mysqld_server-id

Comment: Thanks. However I am wondering if possible to change it for a session (not globally).

Comment: @CrashOverride no, it's a global variable only.

Answer (score 1):

To make the change permanent you need to modify: /etc/my.cnf

Just change the following value:

```
[mysqld]    
server-id=21
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there can be two solution :

**Solution 1 :**

If you having MySQL Instance enabled with GTID, then you can use `gtid_purged` variable to exclude transaction which you don't want to replicate it to slave.

[The global value of the gtid_purged system variable (@@GLOBAL.gtid_purged) is a GTID set consisting of the GTIDs of all the transactions that have been committed on the server, but do not exist in any binary log file on the server. gtid_purged is a subset of gtid_executed.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-gtids.html#sysvar_gtid_purged)

```
That GTID(s) of transactions will be committed in binary logging but will not execute on Slave.
```

**Solution 2 :**

If you instance is not enabled with GTID, then there is no option other than setting `sql_log_bin` because setting `server_id` on session based is not possible.